# What happens when create new brand in Git?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and SourceTree tool. I don't understand why this happens?

My steps: 
 1. Create new brand, named `develop/john/LinksMiddleware/new`
 2. Stages changed files, for more details there're three files. 
 3. Commit

=> Expected: In new brand only contains three staged files in step 2th above 
=> Real result: In new brand contains all source code files as in my local working directory.

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: "brand" or "branch"? Two different things.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a branch then you get something like a copy of original branch. So when you are on master branch and do `git checkout -b "myNewBranch"` then you will have 2 identical copies of your code. You can add changes to them and then merge those changes.